# The word 'None' keeps coming up on every line of output

Tags: python, function, object, printing

For an assignment in class, I am creating objects in a class called student(). It involves user input of student information then afterwards it outputs the student information in a nice format. However, each line in the console window prints out the word 'None' alongside asking the user for input. I am not sure why it's printing out and I want to address the issue.

I believe that the problem lies where I define the function **init**(self) where I assign data members, but I have changed my code multiple ways and have had no luck yet.

```
class student(): 

     def __init__(self):

        self.name = input(print('What is the Student Name?: '))
        self.address = input(print('What is the Student address?: '))
        self.city = input(print('In which city does the Student reside?: '))
        self.state = input(print('In which state does the Student reside?: '))
        self.zip = input(print('In which zip code does the student reside?: '))
        self.id = input(print('What is the Student ID?: '))
        self.gpa = input(print('What is the Student GPA?: '))

        return

def formatInfo(list):

    for student in list:
        print('Student Name: ', student.name)
        print('Address: ', student.address)
        print('City: ', student.city)
        print('State: ', student.state)
        print('Zipcode: ', student.zip)
        print('Student ID: ', student.id)
        print('Student GPA: ', student.gpa)
        print('')

a = student()

b = student()

c = student()

student_list = [a,b,c]

formatInfo(student_list)
```

I expect that the user will only see the question that is asked, not the word 'None' alongside the question.

Comment: Don't call `input` inside `__init__`; let whoever is *instantiating* the class `student` call `input` to gather the necessary information, then pass that information via *arguments* to `student.__init__`. E.g, `name = input(...); adds = input(...); ...; a = student(name, addr, ...)`.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to call `print` inside of `input` - just call `input`:

```
self.name = input('What is the Student Name?: ')
```

What's happening is that `print` is a function which prints the string you pass it, but doesn't return anything.

You're passing the result of `print` to `input`, which prints what you pass it and then waits for input.

Since `print` returns nothing (after printing what you told it), `input` is printing `None`.